# How do you define a nested object to an existing schema in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Say I have two mongoose schemas:

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({ 
       userName: String
     , password: String
})
var AgentSchema = new Schema({
     Name : String
   , Account: AccountSchema
})
```

is there anyway to add AccountSchema to the AgentSchema without it being a collection?

Comment: The `Account` field should probably be an ObjectID pointing to the actual `Account` object data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible. The two solutions are to either use a DocumentId or virtuals:

**ObjectId:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var AccountSchema = new Schema({ 
       userName: String
     , password: String
})
var AgentSchema = new Schema({
     name : String
   , account: {type: ObjectId}
})
```

**Virtuals:**

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({ 
       userName: String
     , password: String
})
var AgentSchema = new Schema({
     name : String
   , _accounts: [AccountSchema]
})

AgentSchema.virtual('account') 
   .set(function(account) { this._accounts[0] = account; }) 
   .get(function() { return this._accounts.first(); });
```